# Expand textarea based on the size of its contents

Tags: html, jquery, css

```css
textarea {
    height: 1.5em;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 2px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

textarea:focus {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <textarea readonly>expand table when clicked to show all data contained herein
      </textarea>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Is there a way, via CSS and/or jQuery, to size an html textarea based on its contents? Specifically, I want the textarea, upon being clicked, to expand so its entire contents are shown.

The snippet shows what I have so far. The textarea expands when clicked, but to an arbitrarily pre-determined size. I'd like the size instead to vary depending on what happens to be in the textarea at the time (it gets loaded from a db).

I've seen some examples where the size expands as the user types. But this is a little different, as the textarea is set to *readonly*.

Comment: Since you are using readonly, why don't you use it in a div instead of textarea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can offer this solution. Using `scrollHeight`. Also, you need to set rule `overflow: hidden` for `textarea` to cancel the scrollbar.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
  textarea.onclick = function() {
    this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight > this.clientHeight) ? (this.scrollHeight) + 'px' : "1.5em";
  }
}
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 80%;
  height: 1.5em;
  padding: 2px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <textarea readonly>expand table when clicked to show all data contained herein
      </textarea>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This snippet works great. Trying to get it to work in my code seems slightly trickier...

Comment: @JWoodchuck, I can help you adapt the code to your project. What are the problems when using this code? What errors do you get in the console?

Comment: Hm, I don't get an error. Rather, the js doesn't seem to recognize the textarea.onclick action.

Comment: @JWoodchuck, I modified the code a bit and now it works like a toggle. Ok. Can you show a screenshot of how you insert the code?

Comment: Looks like I'm getting "Uncaught TypeError: textarea is null"

Comment: @JWoodchuck. Your mistake is understandable. You need to wrap your logic in a window load event - `window.onload = function() { ... }`. I have updated the answer. Check it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226022/discussion-between-sergey-kuznetsov-and-j-woodchuck).